# Gnome restarts when using Wacom Tablet

Tags: gnome, tablet, wacom, 23.04

I'm using a wacom tablet to draw sometimes, but lately I had an issue where the Gnome UI freezes and then restarts when I set the pen onto the tablet. Afterwards, I can use the tablet for a short while normally, and if I don't remove the pen from the detected area of the tablet, everything works fine, it's only when I remove it and then start drawing again.

I looked at the logs and I found the following, but cant seem to get what's causing it.

```
Mai 21 16:18:27 isiko404-Desktop gnome-shell[69331]: GNOME Shell started at Sun May 21 2023 16:18:25 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
Mai 21 16:18:27 isiko404-Desktop gnome-shell[69331]: Registering session with GDM
Mai 21 16:18:27 isiko404-Desktop gnome-shell[69331]: JS ERROR: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: error occurred in AboutToShow
                                                     _promisify/proto[asyncFunc]/</<@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:453:45
                                                     ### Promise created here: ###
                                                     sendAboutToShow@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/dbusMenu.js:501:48
                                                     sendAboutToShow@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/dbusMenu.js:197:22
                                                     attachToMenu@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/dbusMenu.js:864:24
                                                     _updateMenu/this._menuReadyId<@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/indicatorStatusI>
                                                     _callHandlers@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/_signals.js:130:42
                                                     _emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/_signals.js:119:10
                                                     AppIndicatorsClient/<@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/dbusMenu.js:835:24
                                                     _updateLayoutState@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/dbusMenu.js:365:18
                                                     _layoutUpdateUpdateAsync@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/dbusMenu.js:346:18
                                                     async*_beginLayoutUpdate@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/dbusMenu.js:326:14
                                                     _requestLayoutUpdate@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/dbusMenu.js:276:14
                                                     initAsync@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/dbusMenu.js:254:14
                                                     async*AppIndicatorsClient@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/dbusMenu.js:829:22
                                                     _updateMenu@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/indicatorStatusIcon.js:318:32
                                                     _showIfReady@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/indicatorStatusIcon.js:339:14
                                                     _init@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/indicatorStatusIcon.js:256:14
                                                     ButtonBox@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/panelMenu.js:11:1
                                                     PanelMenuButton@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/panelMenu.js:97:4
                                                     AppIndicatorsIndicatorBaseStatusIcon@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/indicatorS>
                                                     AppIndicatorsIndicatorStatusIcon@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/indicatorStatu>
                                                     _registerItem@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/statusNotifierWatcher.js:118:32
                                                     async*_ensureItemRegistered@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/statusNotifierWatch>
                                                     RegisterStatusNotifierItemAsync@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/statusNotifierW>
                                                     async*_handleMethodCall@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:373:35
                                                     _wrapJSObject/<@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:408:34
Mai 21 16:18:27 isiko404-Desktop gnome-shell[69331]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x556ed33f4020] is on because it needs an allocatio>
Mai 21 16:18:27 isiko404-Desktop gnome-shell[69331]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x556ed33f8910] is on because it needs an allocati>
Mai 21 16:18:27 isiko404-Desktop gnome-shell[69331]: Trying to set property Menu of type s but according to the expected interface the type is o
Mai 21 16:18:28 isiko404-Desktop gnome-shell[69331]: Trying to set property Menu of type s but according to the expected interface the type is o
Mai 21 16:18:29 isiko404-Desktop gnome-shell[69331]: Trying to set property Menu of type s but according to the expected interface the type is o
Mai 21 16:18:29 isiko404-Desktop gnome-shell[69331]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x556ed344d6b0] is on because it needs an allocatio>
Mai 21 16:18:29 isiko404-Desktop gnome-shell[69331]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x556ed344da90] is on because it needs an allocati>
Mai 21 16:18:29 isiko404-Desktop gnome-shell[69331]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x556ed3452e60] is on because it needs an allocatio>
Mai 21 16:18:29 isiko404-Desktop gnome-shell[69331]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x556ed3454140] is on because it needs an allocati>
Mai 21 16:18:30 isiko404-Desktop gnome-shell[69331]: Trying to set property Menu of type s but according to the expected interface the type is o
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you deactivate gnome shell extensions?

Comment: I allready tried that